# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError- unable to open a second activity

Tags: android, android-studio

So I had the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` error, and was unable to open my app. I added `android:hardwareAccelerated="false" and android:largeHeap="true"` to the AndroidManifest.xml, but now I'm unable to open my next activity when clicking on a button. The app will crash with the below error. The second activity has one image, 2 text views and 5 buttons.

```
11-05 04:33:17.420 15163-15163/? E/Zygote: v2
11-05 04:33:17.430 15163-15163/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
11-05 04:33:22.670 15163- 
15163/dev.ddc.josephsiccita.diamonddancechallenge E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: dev.ddc.josephsiccita.diamonddancechallenge, PID: 15163
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 568189452 byte allocation with 16765568 free bytes and 357MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4211)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2005)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1987)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:464)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at dev.ddc.josephsiccita.diamonddancechallenge.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: How big is the image? My guess is the image needs to be resized.

Comment: @Notsileous it is a large-ish image. Do I have to manually resize the file and is there a set size for the images?

Comment: Depends on the initial size and where you are putting it. If you are filling a 50x50 image view with a 1000x1000 image you might as well manually resize it something closer to the display size so its less work for the app.

Comment: @Notsileous so basically I should resize all the images so they are as similar as to what they actually are.. this should resolve my issue? No code needed?

Comment: Probably you are using to much memory in order to process/show the image. Try to use an image handler library, like Glide, Picasso, or Fresco. Manage image directly with bitmaps is a bad idea.